# Compute the order of the zero of $f(z)$

Tags: complex-analysis

Compute the order of the zero of $f(z)=e^z-1$ at each of its zeroes.

I know that the zeroes of this function is when $z=2k\pi i$, $k\in \mathbb{Z}$. I also know the answer for $z_0=0$, but I am not so sure how to transform $f(z)$ into the form $(z-z_0)^k g(z)$ when $z_0 \neq 0$. Do I have to plug the $z_0$ into $f(z)$?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Do you mean multiplicity instead of zero?

Comment: Try computing the power series expansion about each zero...

Comment: expand $e^z$ into a powerseries and differentiate

Comment: How do I compute the power series about each zero? Do I plug in the zero into $f(z)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $f'(z)=e^z$, we immediately see that $f'(z)\neq0$ whenever $f(z)=0$. (In fact $f'\neq0$ everywhere.) Hence all the zeros are simple.

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by "all zeroes are simple"?

Comment: @verticese Multiplicity (or "order" using your terminology) one.